# One button make open new activity and random letters

Tags: javascript, java, android, performance

I want a help plz how I can click on button in activity (1) and showed random letter in 
next activity (2)  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first activity you can do that in onCreate:

```
         // To generate a random char in a-z : 
         Random r = new Random();
         char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

         // here you are gonna move to another activity

         Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, 
                       SecondActivity.class);

         // here you pass the value of random letter to the second activity
         intent.putExtra("random_letter", c);


         startActivity(intent);
```

Now you are going to move to the second activity and pass the value of the random letter.

In second activity, you can do this :

```
  // here you get the value of random letter from the first activity and 

   Intent intent = getIntent();

   //store it in random_letter

  String random_letter = intent.getStringExtra("random_letter");
```

By doing this in second activity, you get the value of random letter from the first activity and store it in random_letter, so you can be able to use it in the second activity.

Comment: please don't answer posts like these, it doesn't help the community

Comment: Please if you have suggestion for my answer to be better, share it and I will listen. If you do so, it will help me to learn and it will help the community. Anyways, I will edit my answer with further explanation.

Comment: i don't have any problems with your answer :) but if you answer people who show no effort then the community doesnt get any better

Comment: First of all he tagget javascrip and java

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center

Comment: Dude, it's better to let him learn how to do it in a better way than just blaming him, he maybe a noob and that may affect him in a bad way. Let's all agree that we all here to learn not just get our questions answered but to learn how to ask, how to answer, how to make a good use of the answer, .. etc. Thanks for your care about the community, I appreciate it but we all here are learning seekers.